# How to use BSTR*

Tags: com, bstr

I have an `out` value as BSTR* for an interface in a C++ COM dll. And I am returning this to a C# .Net client. In my C++ function I have to assign different values according to a diff condition.

For example:

```
If my function is fun(BSTR* outval)
{
   // I have to assign a default value to it such as:
   *outval = SysAllocSTring(L"N");

   Then I will check for some DB conditions
   { 
     // And I have to allocate it according to that.
     // Do I need to again calling SysAllocString?
     eq.*outval = SySAllocString(DBVlaue);
   }
}
```

What happens if I call SysAllocSTring two times to the same BSTR? What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 9):

You have to take care of all `BSTR`s except the one you actually pass as the "out" parameter. The `BSTR` you pass out need not be freed - the caller becomes responsible for freeing it, and your code is responsible for all other `BSTR`s it could have allocated.

If you really need those temporary `BSTR`s you should use a wrapper class like `ATL::CComBSTR` or `_bstr_t` for those temporary `BSTR`s (but not for the one you pass out). I guess in the case you describe you'll be much better off just rewriting your code in such way that you don't need more that one `BSTR` creation on any control path.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
 HRESULT YourFunction( BSTR* result )
 {
     if( result == 0 ) {
         return E_POINTER;
     }
     int internalStateValue = getState();
     if( internalStateValue > 0 ) { // first case
         *result = SysAllocString( "positive" );
     } else if( internalStateValue < 0 ) { //second case
         *result = SysAllocString( "negative" );
     } else { //default case
         *result = SysAllocString( "zero" );
     }
     return S_OK;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from what Martyn has answered, you should try using [CComBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx) for this which will automatically take care of allocation and freeing the BSTRs.

BTW, CComBSTR class is an example of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Answer (score 2):

If you call SysAllocString twice, you will leak the first BSTR. You should not do this. You can instead SysFreeString on the first BSTR and then SysAllocString on a second, or more simply call SysReAllocString to reallocate your existing BSTR value.

Martyn

Answer (score 0):

If you function defined as:

```
HRESULT Foo(BSTR input){...}
```

Call it like:

```
Foo(_bstr_t(L"abc"));
```